# Vectorization when mapping between indices in an assignment is not injective

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

Suppose that `c` is a scalar value, `T` and `W` are `M-by-N` matrices, `k` is another `M-by-N` matrix containing values from `1` to `M` (and there are at least two pairs `(i1, j1)`, `(i2, j2)` such that `k(i1, j1)==k(i2, j2)`) and `a` is a `1-by-M` vector. I want to vectorize the following code (hoping that this will speed it up):

```
T = zeros(M,N);
for j = 1:N
    for i = 1:M
        T(k(i,j),j) = T(k(i,j),j) + c*W(i,j)/a(i);
    end
end
```

Do you have any tips so that I can vectorize this code (or make it faster in general)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you use `T(k(i,j),j)` to create `T(k(i,j),j)` it make no sense ?

Comment: Please provide a small numeric example of what you're trying to do. It's unclear to me what the question is about.

Comment: I get the sense that any vectorized solution might actually end up being slower than a simple set of loops in this case. Will be interesting to see...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `k` only ever effects how values are aggregated *within* a column, but not *between* columns, you can achieve a slight speedup by reducing the problem to a single loop over columns and using [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) like so:

```
T = zeros(M, N);
for col = 1:N
  T(:, col) = accumarray(k(:,col), c*W(:, col)./a, [M 1]);
end
```

I tested each of the solutions (the loop in your question, [rahnema's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348012/52738), [Divakar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41349432/52738), and mine) by taking the average of 100 iterations using input values initialized as in Divakar's answer. Here's what I got (running Windows 7 x64, 16 GB RAM, MATLAB R2016b):

```
solution | avg. time (s) | max(abs(err)) 
---------+---------------+---------------
loop     |       0.12461 | 0 
rahnema  |       0.84518 | 0 
divakar  |       0.12381 | 1.819e-12 
gnovice  |       0.09477 | 0
```

The take-away: loops actually aren't so bad, but if you can simplify them into one it can save you a little time.

Comment: Possible improvement would be with pre-computing `cWa = bsxfun(@times,W,c/a);` (of course if memory allows for really large arrays) and using it within loops. Seems to be giving around 20% speedup.

Comment: @Divakar: When I precompute with `bsxfun`, it actually slows down the solution and introduces small errors. Weird.

Comment: Hmm could it be version issue? I tested on MATLAB 2012a. Don't have access to newer version. Maybe we should be using `timeit`.

Comment: @Divakar: I think newer versions do handle loops much more efficiently, and the errors *could* be machine-precision order-of-operation errors (amplified by very small random values in `a`). `tic/toc` should be fine, since I was timing 100 iterations.

Comment: @Divakar: Done. Your solution sped up (close to the double-loop one now), but the error is still there. It has to be coming from `bsxfun`, I guess?

Comment: That `1.819e-12` error? Maybe because its summing in one go, which is different from summing one by one in a loop, so that tiny difference? I guess I have seen this disparity between loops and vectorized methods before. Maybe `accumarray`? But accumarray is summing only one column at a time in both cases... so I am not sure! Something peculiar/interesting thing going on there.

Comment: @gnovice: I tested your approach and got the same results. In my real application your solution led to an even bigger improvement than the test suggests. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with a combination of [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) -

```
% Create 2D array of unique IDs along each col to be used as flattened subs
id = bsxfun(@plus,k,M*(0:N-1));

% Compute "c*W(i,j)/a(i)" for all i's and j's
cWa = c*bsxfun(@rdivide,W,a);

% Accumulate final result for all cols
out = reshape(accumarray(id(:),reshape(cWa,[],1),[M*N 1]),[M,N]);
```

### Benchmarking

Approaches as functions -

```
function out = func1(W,a,c,k,M,N)
id = bsxfun(@plus,k,M*(0:N-1));
cWa = c*bsxfun(@rdivide,W,a);
out = reshape(accumarray(id(:),reshape(cWa,[],1),[M*N 1]),[M,N]);

function T = func2(W,a,c,k,M,N)  % @rahnema1's solution
[I J] = meshgrid(1:M,1:N);
idx1 = sub2ind([M N], I ,J);
R = c.* W(idx1) ./ a(I);
T = accumarray([k(idx1(:)) ,J(:)], R(:),[M N]);

function T = func3(W,a,c,k,M,N)  % Original approach
T = zeros(M,N);
for j = 1:N
    for i = 1:M
        T(k(i,j),j) = T(k(i,j),j) + c*W(i,j)/a(i);
    end
end

function T = func4(W,a,c,k,M,N) % @gnovice's solution
T = zeros(M, N);
for col = 1:N
  T(:, col) = accumarray(k(:,col), c*W(:, col)./a, [M 1]);
end
```

Machine setup : Kubuntu 16.04, MATLAB  2012a, 4GB RAM.

Timing code  -

```
% Setup inputs
M = 3000;
N = 3000;
W = rand(M,N);
a = rand(M,1);
c = 2.34;
k = randi([1,M],[M,N]);

disp('------------------ With func1')
tic,out = func1(W,a,c,k,M,N);toc
clear out

disp('------------------ With func2')
tic,out = func2(W,a,c,k,M,N);toc
clear out

disp('------------------ With func3')
tic,out = func3(W,a,c,k,M,N);toc
clear out

disp('------------------ With func4')
tic,out = func4(W,a,c,k,M,N);toc
```

Timing code run -

```
------------------ With func1
Elapsed time is 0.215591 seconds.
------------------ With func2
Elapsed time is 1.555373 seconds.
------------------ With func3
Elapsed time is 0.572668 seconds.
------------------ With func4
Elapsed time is 0.291552 seconds.
```

**Possible improvements in proposed approach**

1] In `c*bsxfun(@rdivide,W,a)`, we are use two stages of `broadcasting` - One at `bsxfun(@rdivide,W,a)`, where `a` is broadcasted ; Second one when `c` is broadcasted to *match-up* against the 2D output of `bsxfun(@rdivide,W,a)`, though we don't need `bsxfun` for this one. So, a possible improvement would be if we *insert-in* `c` to be divided by `a`, where `c` would be only broadcasted to `1D`, instead of `2D` and then the second level of broadcasting would be`1D`: `c/a` to `2D` : `W` just like before. This minor improvement could be timed -

```
>> tic, c*bsxfun(@rdivide,W,a); toc
Elapsed time is 0.073244 seconds.
>> tic, bsxfun(@times,W,c/a); toc
Elapsed time is 0.041745 seconds.
```

But, in cases where `c` and `a` differ by a lot, the scaling factor `c/a` would affect the final result by appreciably. So, one need to be careful with this suggestion.

Comment: It seems that matlab jit compiler produces very optimized code.

Comment: @rahnema1 At least we are able to beat loops somehow :)

Comment: Have you checked that all the outputs are the same for each method? When I tested it rahnema's solution matched the loop output but yours didn't.

Comment: @gnovice Could be because of the *hacky* initialization with `out(M*N)=0;`? Well I edited to a proper initialization with `zeros` and seems to be okay now. Could you check again with the edited `func1`?

Comment: @Divakar: Looks good. I was using `isequal` instead of calculating the error. Just small deviations.

Comment: @Divakar: Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
[I J] = meshgrid(1:M,1:N);
idx1 = sub2ind([M N], I ,J);
R = c.* W(idx1) ./ a(I);
T = accumarray([K(idx1(:)) ,J(:)], R(:),[M N]);
```

Comparison of different methods in Octave without jit:

```
------------------ Divakar
Elapsed time is 0.282008 seconds.
------------------ rahnema1
Elapsed time is 1.08827 seconds.
------------------ gnovice
Elapsed time is 0.418701 seconds.
------------------ loop
doesn't complete in 15 seconds.
```